# how to extract dynamic number of queryparameter values separated by comma in URL in APIGEE

Tags: apigee

for Eg. in-
http://myorg-test.apigee.net/v1/weather/forecastrss?w=12797282,4342&code=aepp

how to extract 12797282 and 4342 as 2 different variable. Tried usisng Javascript node but could not find the solution.

Comment: You do indeed need to use Javascript to do that. Post your code and we'll see what we can do.

Answer (score 1):

using javascript.. 
read query parameter to variable and split 
var myParam=request.queryParams.w;
var myParamArray=myParam.split(",");